# Using only selected values from a Combo-Box(range) to perform a repeat task

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have a combobox which populates integer values from Access database table. 
This table lists values typically (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 .. and so on) but for example if the user has deleted any values in between then the combobox values may look like (1, 3,4,6,7,8,10). 
I carry out exporting excel workbook with a WorkSheet Name based on each values. In case where I have the missing values, in my For - Next loop, the program gets stuck after 1. It does not jump to value 3. Is it possible in this case to get the list of only available values in the Combobox and then carry out export only for these valid available values?

UPDATE: Solved with help from Viktor...

```
For Each item As Object In ComboBox1.Items

Dim drv As DataRowView = item  'ComboBox1.SelectedItem
Dim value As Integer = drv("Unique_ID").ToString
     'StartNo and EndNo specify the range 
 If (value >= StartNo) And (value <= EndNo) Then
ComboBox1.SelectedValue = value 
   xlWorkSheet.Name = ("EmpNo_" & value)
   ' do the export task 
end if 

Next
```

Comment: How does the `For` loop look? Please edit your question and add your current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
For Each item As Object In ComboBox1
    'Value will hold the value of the item, e.g. 1,3,4,6,7,8,10
    'To compare it we will convert the item to a Single type (a number) using CSng()
    Dim value As Single = CSng(item.ToString)

    'Export if values are between 4 and 10
    If (value > 4) and (value < 10) Then
        'Export

        /.../
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Many thanks.. I forgot to mention one thing which is if I have to export only a range like values between 4 and 10 (both 4 & 10 inclusive ) will it be possible? My code is too big to post so I am trying to see if I can reduce to a minimum which is easy to post here.. would appreciate your reply though in the meantime..

Comment: Of course, with a simple `If` statement. Edited my answer. Good luck!

Comment: Hi,  many thanks for your help. I first encountered problem as my combobox was connected to datasource and getting error as ""System.Data.DataRowView" to type 'Single' is not valid". So I did following and now its working as expected. I will add code to main post..